# How can I open and run the blink example from the STM32F3 MCU package?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

I have previously written, compiled and flashed applications to an STM32F3 Discovery board succesfully with the STM32CubeIDE.

ST offers an [STM32Cube MCU Package for STM32F3 series](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef3.html), which I downloaded to try some of the examples. I have a hard time following the instructions (see screenshot below) to open the example projects given in the file */Documentation/STM32CubeF3GettingStarted.pdf*. I try to follow the instructions for TrueSTUDIO, given that it's the predecessor of STM32CubeIDE.

Problems:

- I'm supposed to use a TrueSTUDIO directory as workspace, but there's no such directory. Am I supposed to create it?
- Later I'm supposed to browse to that directory to open the project:

  > **Browse** to the *TrueSTUDIO* workspace directory, select the project

  I cannot find a TrueSTUDIO specific project folder or file (see screenshot at the end of this question), there's only EWARM, MDK-ARM and SW4STM32.

**How can I open an example project in STM32CubeIDE?**

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Probably it would be better to ask in STM32 forum.

Answer (score 0):

I program the stmf103 development boards using the Arduino IDE as programing BLINK on a BLUEPILL taught me a few tricks mainly using RX and TX along with a programing module you can have a lot of fun and make the chip do what you want it to do and yes the CUBE by stm does teach you what each of the pins can do and its up to you to make them do what you want. I am an experimenter (retired) and had to learn on my own ,each winter I learn a little more which is ok as it keeps my brain alive.

Answer (score -2):

Few Google clicks, gives me this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnmjmP2Xchg

and this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RqUkFIeN6w

Have you tried?